# PuTTY - Automatic Reconnect After Internet Interruption?

Tags: putty

After a small hiccup in internet connection, any open PuTTY windows throw up a message box saying there was a connection error.  Is there a way to automate retry attempts?  Or better yet, tell it to watch the status of the network and reconnect when internet access is reestablished?

I know there's the "stackoverflow" solution of writing a program that invokes PuTTY using its command line interface using -load and -pw.  But I'm looking for a "superuser" solution because that seems like less work.

Should I look into Tunnelier instead?

Background:
I'm using an SSH tunnel with port forwarding to get remote access to a database on BlueHost.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Tunnelier](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client) provides the functionality I was seeking.

It is free:

> Our client is free for use of all types, including in organizations.

Comment: Didn't it only be free for personal use? There was a 2GB file limit for the FTP to SCP bridge. Also Tunnelier is now called "Bitvise SSH Client"

Answer (score 40):

Kitty is a forked version of putty that adds reconnect, send to tray and stored username/password.  The auto reconnect works after the machine awakes from sleep as well.   It's been very stable for me.  FREE :)

Comment: Download: http://www.fosshub.com/KiTTY.html

Comment: The auto reconnect options are on the middle of the "Connection" page under "Reconnect options". I wasn't sure at first if this feature was automatic or a setting

Comment: The official site: http://kitty.9bis.net/

Comment: It is [open source](https://github.com/niieani/kitty-remix)

Comment: I cannot find where to specify auto reconnect in KiTTY, where is it? I am looking under "Connection"

Comment: I upgraded KiTTY and now my terminal background image disappeared https://superuser.com/questions/1525875/does-kitty-still-support-background-image-for-terminal

Comment: Confirm Kitty reconnects after connection failure. Works like a charm!

Comment: KiTTY also displayed and loaded my no-so-simple PuTTY tunnelling & password-less configuration without any change needed. The most pleasent software surprise I have had for years.

Comment: Works well, even re-establishes SSH tunnels but _only_ if the previous tunnel got to shut down (i.e. time out) - so it doesn't work in all cases on tunnels

Comment: NOTE : https://kitty.9bis.net/ is now offline. seems new url is https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!index.md

Answer (score 13):

There's also a fork of PuTTY called PuTTY Tray which adds a "reconnect on connection failure" option (albeit experimental): https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/

Comment: Looks like it would also solve my problem.  Thanks

Comment: [BETA: 0.67-t029 (2016-06-26)](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/) Note: Automatic reconnection is deprecated. It doesn't work. Please disable it.

Comment: Can confirm, doesn't work. Too bad. :(

Answer (score 4):

Might not be as useful or convenient for you as it is for me, but I use screen in my ssh sessions and it has the option of resuming and a broken connection with screen -R so long as you connect to the same server (my uni provide 3 servers which they can allocate or you can explicitly choose).

Comment: I use screen and it is very useful, however I have tunnels setup in KiTTY and would rather get auto reconnect there. I already have different settings in BitVise SSH Client. PuTTY, KiTTY can have multiple sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mutli tabbing putty http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/ which allows to reconnect the session back. Beside bringing the session back it allows multi tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that might help is the "Enable TCP Keepalives" option under Connection.

Comment: See my comment on jfmessier's answer

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to re-establish an EXISTING connection, as the shared key created during the connection, and renewed on a regular basis might get our of sync, or outdated. At this point, this would have to be re-initialised, using your own private key with the server.

Enable TCP Keepalives might be the only solution here.

Comment: My situation is: I use the connection rather frequently and it should never be idle for more than a minute.  My issue is when the internet disconnects for a few seconds, so does my session.  ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax seem like they MIGHT work but I'm not sure how to configure those with PuTTY...

Comment: Under PuTTY configuration, in the list on the left, click Connection. On the right, you will see items such as "Seconds between keepalives (0 to turn off)" 0 is the default value. You can also play with the Low-level TCP connection options.

Comment: Key re-exchange requires acknowledgement from the other end... "out of sync" can't happen.

Comment: TCP keepalive or SSH keepalive null packets do not help to keep the connection open in case the communication is broken. Contrary these settings will help to realize that the communication is nonfunctional sooner and consequently bring the SSH connection down sooner. --- The keepalive messages are important in case there are long periods without communication - to keep the communication open on stateful devices (like dynamic NAT or firewall).

Answer (score 0):

You can use screen on the server side, and setup a passwordless auth to putty with a low timeout.