# PuttyTray won't reconnect after dropped connections

Tags: ssh, shell

According to this questions:

[PuTTY - Automatic Reconnect After Internet Interruption?](https://superuser.com/questions/187293/putty-automatic-reconnect-after-internet-interruption)

"Tunnelier" is the answer, but I'm wondering if anyone could expound on why Putty/PuttyTray/WhateverPuttyMods don't keep the connection alive/restart when it drops? Or perhaps point me to a working solution that they have personal experience with?

WinSCP has no problem doing this using an SSH connection, so it's gotta be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just used Tunnelier instead, since no one responded and I can't find anything on the Interwebs. Too bad. Tunnelier's shell is far worse, and I still use plink for some Logstalgia magic. Oh well.