# How to avoid Putty connection reset

Tags: putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PuTTY - Automatic Reconnect After Internet Interruption?](https://superuser.com/questions/187293/putty-automatic-reconnect-after-internet-interruption)

I use putty from my Win XP host, to ssh to a ARM based development board with Linux on it. As a part of my dev/debug process I constantly reboot the board, after which my putty connection gives connection reset error and I have to repeat the login process by starting different putty connection. Its irritating as there are 5-6 terms i need open.

Is there any terminal connection software which would not reset and restore its connection state(if there is anything like this at all?)

Or

In putty settings is there any config option to get what I am trying to do?

Comment: check the link above, there are several solutions

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to do what you want to do. When you reboot, you will lose connection, no matter what you're using to connect. That's part of what a reboot does.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/), a shell implementation for mobile connections.

Getting it running on Windows is a little bit [more complicated](http://www.zacpod.com/?p=221).

I does an automatic reconnect if connection is lost. Maybe its less secure than SSH, but this shouldn't be a problem in your case.