# Can I supress the "server unexpectedly closed network connection" window from Putty?

Tags: putty, window

When I have a bunch of sessions running and then lose my VPN connection, rather than just being able to close all my putty windows that were terminated and start over, I have to go to each window and click on the 'OK' within the "server unexpectedly closed network connection" window. I'd like it if I wasn't shown this window. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try changing "Close window on exit:" from "Only on clean exit" to "Always".

If that doesn't work -- there is a lot of forks of PuTTY that add features.  Look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/187293/putty-automatic-reconnect-after-internet-interruption) to start.

Comment: Hmmm, this might work out.  Now when the disconnect occurs all the windows will be gone.  Seems to do the same thing with Always or Never.  I'll try this for a while and see if it works out the way I want.  Hopefully it still logs all my session still. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may kill all PuTTy instances by running the following batch command:

```
taskkill /f putty.exe
```

In case that PuTTy doesn't terminate itself, use the forceful method:

```
taskkill /f /im putty.exe
```

(Note: The `.exe` name is just a guess - I don't use PuTTy.)