# Wait for the server in PuTTy

Tags: ssh, putty, session-restore

Is there any run switch or configuration setting in PuTTY for Windows that instead of showing me this screen:

[image]

Would rather ask me a question, if I want to wait some time and try to reestablish the same connection as previously? I've seen simiar solutions many times in many other apps.

I am doing some research on my RaspberryPi and so I must reboot it often. Sometimes even 20-30 times per hour. It drives me crazy that each time I click *OK* in above dialog box, PuTTy quits completely and I have to:

- Hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to minimise all the apps
- Look for the PuTTy's icon on my desktop or hit <kbd>Start</kbd>, type *Put* and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Double click session settings in the list again to start up the same session again

Is there any way to prevent this, make this a little bit more automated etc.?

**EDIT:** *My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/187293/156554) because all answers provided there talks about different software (a large number of PuTTy's forks). While I ask specifically about "core" / "original" PuTTy. And for that reason only the answer given below seems valid*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PuTTY - Automatic Reconnect After Internet Interruption?](https://superuser.com/questions/187293/putty-automatic-reconnect-after-internet-interruption)

Comment: @harrymc Nope! :> Clarified in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your PuTTY connection profile has:

```
Close window on exit:
(*) Only on clean exit
```

(If this doesn't help, choose "Never.")

With this option selected, the window will remain open so you can Ctrl+Right-click it and select <kbd>D</kbd> "Duplicate Session" or even <kbd>R</kbd> "Restart Session" every time the connection is closed.

To start PuTTY quickly, press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and enter `putty`. You can append the hostname to the command (e.g. `putty root@pi`) or load a saved profile (e.g. `putty -load "My Raspberry"`).

Comment: A very comprehensive answer. Thank you. Upvoted and accepted.